# Apple Swift MacOS - How to Show Help Book?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

**How to open the Help Book of a MacOS app?**

I found `showHelp()` but that's not in scope in my app.

`showContextHelp()` is in scope but that doesn't open the Help Book.

`showHelp()` docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1500910-showhelp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anchors in help-book not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913937/anchors-in-help-book-not-working)

Comment: @Willeke, yeah I was there before here. helioz's comment linked in my answer worked for me. Thanks for the assist! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @helioz here worked:

> To call an anchor is swift 4:
> `NSHelpManager.shared.openHelpAnchor(NSHelpManager.AnchorName(rawValue:"MyAnchor"), inBook: NSHelpManager.BookName(rawValue: "com.company.App.help") )` –
> helioz Mar 13 '18 at 12:59

From:
[Anchors in help-book not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913937/anchors-in-help-book-not-working#comment85516651_14913937)